# How to serialize with Map<String, dynamic> using the package built_value

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, built-value

Does anyone know how can I serialize/deserialize a Map<String, dynamic> instead of String that is the default in the `toJson` e `fromJson` methods of the [built_value package](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value)?

I need to use Firestore and the setData method only accepts a Map for the data.

My current Serializer class has the code below. There's some other plugin or config that I can add to work with the map?

```
final Serializers serializers =
    (_$serializers.toBuilder()..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())).build();
```

Here are the methods:

```
 String toJson() {
    return json.encode(serializers.serializeWith(Comment.serializer, this));
  }

  static Comment fromJson(String jsonString) {
    return serializers.deserializeWith(
        Comment.serializer, json.decode(jsonString));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `toJson` method should look like:

```dart
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return serializers.serializeWith(PlayerModel.serializer, this);
  }
```

That is get rid of the `json.encode`.

Similarly for `fromJson`:

```dart
  static PlayerModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return serializers.deserializeWith(PlayerModel.serializer, json);
  }
```

Here is a sample PlayerModel I use:

```dart
abstract class PlayerModel implements Built<PlayerModel, PlayerModelBuilder> {
  @nullable
  String get uid;
  String get displayName;

  PlayerModel._();
  factory PlayerModel([void Function(PlayerModelBuilder) updates]) =
      _$PlayerModel;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return serializers.serializeWith(PlayerModel.serializer, this);
  }

  static PlayerModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return serializers.deserializeWith(PlayerModel.serializer, json);
  }

  static Serializer<PlayerModel> get serializer => _$playerModelSerializer;
}
```

Comment: I'm having the following error when applying your solution: `A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from the method 'toJson' because it has a return type of 'Map<String, dynamic>'.` Any idea why?

Comment: I've descibed my issue there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67742383/error-while-serializing-builtobject-using-built-value-combined-with-flutterfir